# What is the secret of Superman's suit?

Tags: dc, superman, the-new-52

In Superman #11 the cover reads:
[image]

Now I know covers have a tendency to be a little... misrepresentative of what is actually contained in the issue, but I've read the issue twice. There doesn't seem to be any secret about it.

Comment: Josh at IGN was similarly bewildered: "[The only thing revealed about the suit are some errors by the art team](http://www.ign.com/articles/2012/07/25/superman-11-review)". ;)

Comment: Hmmm... It's a little strange to see Superman wearing his undies under his clothes. I guess even Superman is vunerable to peer pressure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I hate to break it to you, but the secret of the suit is:

- Superman finally gets to join the instant-costume changing club. He was for a long time, the only member of the Justice League who had a secret identity but could not instantly change into his supersuit. Batman had his bat-cave, Wonder Woman spun around, Flash compressed his into his yellow ring, Hal Jordan used his power ring to convert his street clothes, the Atom just shrank into his, The Martian Manhunter shape-changes. Superman does this:

[image: Superman changing in a phone-booth]

- His armored Kryptonian bio-tech suit allows him to change his clothes without having to find a phone booth or having to wear the same blue suit, white shirt and red tie, that he did for decades before the Pre-Crisis reboot. The specially treated suit that could be compressed into his supercape, without wrinkling.

[image]

- Post-Crisis, they didn't explain what happened to his clothes, he just got to wear outfits that were not blue, red or white. The clothes just disappeared.

[image]

- He can finally wear a shirt without a tie because his super-tee would be showing at the neck.

[image]

This is an amazing upgrade for the Man of Steel. It only took him twenty six years before he could do the same thing Spider-Man did after the Secret Wars with his black costume.

Robot Chicken did enjoy themselves with this bit as well: What happens to Superman clothes while he's out "[saving lives](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hs-w5aoWr9U)?"

Comment: It has been established many years ago that Superman folds his civilian clothes super-tight and stores them in a pouch in his cape. You can even see him doing it in the second-to-last image (the "grateful for commercials" one).

Comment: In Post Crisis, they did not clarify the hiding of his civilian clothing in his cape as they did in the Pre-Crisis version.

Comment: Wait, why would Superman need an armored suit?