# Does Superman's costume in the New 52 have a special function or purpose?

Tags: dc, superman, the-new-52

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the secret of Superman's suit?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21910/what-is-the-secret-of-supermans-suit)

We've all seen what Superman's New 52 costume looks like, but does it have a special function?

Does it absorb yellow sunlight for Superman's body? Does it shapeshift into his Clark Kent clothes? Is it traditional Krytonian clothing, did everyone on his planet wear that? Is it a Kryptonian soldier's uniform, if so why is he wearing it, he was never in their army? Is it a Kryptonian funeral costume he wears because his planet's gone? Is it a symbiotic lifeform?

Comment: We have already answered this in the question: [What is the secret of Superman's suit?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21910/what-is-the-secret-of-supermans-suit)