# Does Clark Kent need to get a new shirt every time he turns into Superman?

Tags: dc, superman, smallville

I was recently watching an episode of Smallville where Clark rips open his shirt and a button pinged off a wall. Besides making me laugh, it made me think: shirts don't open that easily without the buttons flying all over the place and needing to be repaired/replaced. Maybe there are velcro shirts he would use?

On the same track, where does he keep his clothes when he's in the red and blue?

Comment: I read that, but it still left me with questions. What about before he got the "Kryptonian bio-tech"? Is it just that they took artistic license and didn't explain it? I'm just thinking that, in 80 years of Superman, someone must have tried to explain this.

Comment: If you would like clarification on Thaddeus' answer, you should leave a comment on it. Hopefully he can expand his answer there.

Comment: He crushes the old suit into a diamond and uses that to buy another suit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second question is covered in this answer to [What is the secret of Superman's suit?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/21914/1148)

To the first question, several possibilities come to mind

- Superman's superior speed and dexterity allow him to unbutton his shirt without damaging it in the blink of an eye
- Superman's superior intellect enabled him to wisely invest in snap button shirts
- Superman spends his off evenings re-sewing the buttons onto his favorite shirt.

You said in the episode you watched, a button did break off. Was this the first instance of Clark Kent changing in this manner? Maybe after this first time he would adopt one of the alternatives listed above.

[image]

Comment: Sewing at super speed?